# Application.Match gives type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use `Application.Match` however it is returning a `type mismatch error:13` error. Why?

```
Dim mySrs as Series
Dim ws as Worksheet
set ws Activesheet
For Each mySrs in ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
tempvar = mySrs.Name
y = Application.Match(tempvar, ws.Range("P37:P71"), 0)
MsgBox y
```

Comment: Why not use a `Range.Find()` method?

Comment: Apparently, Find is typically slower than Match: [fastexcel.wordpress.com](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In all likelihood, no match is found. In such a case, `Application.Match` returns an Excel error code i.e. a Variant/Error whose value is `Error 2042` (this corresponds to getting `#N/A` in Excel).

Such an Error value cannot be implicitly coerced to a String (which is what `MsgBox` expects) and thus you get the type mismatch.

Note that the same `Match` function can be called using `WorksheetFunction.Match`. The only difference is how errors are to be handled:

- With `WorksheetFunction`, errors are treated as VBA errors, trappable using the `On Error` syntax.
- With `Application`, they return an Excel error code wrapped in a Variant. You can use `IsError` to see if the returned variable is an Error type variant.

Comment: ah that was my problem! I was looking for "25%" but of course the worksheet had that as .25 rather than a string. Thank you