# Unable to get Match property of the WorksheetFunction class

Tags: vba, excel

What I'm trying to do is based on a Cell `oSht_Input.Cells(Rows, 7)` , I want to find a match in another Sheet's (periodSheet) Column A, and get the corresponding value based on a given column.

I have tried combining the usage of `.Index` and `.Match` to do this. the `.Index` works for me, however I'm getting and error that says

> Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class.

I have also tried doing `Application.Match` in the codes, but that would return me a `#N/A` Value instead.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm a little bit confused the usage of `Application.Match` and `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match`.

```
Set oSht_Input = Worksheets(outSheet)
Set periodSheet = Worksheets("PeriodMetadata")
lastRow = oSht_Input.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For Rows = 2 To lastRow
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        dateCell = oSht_Input.Cells(Rows, 7)
        If rollupDataFile.GroupByPeriod Like "Week*" Then
            If rollupDataFile.GroupByPeriod Like "*Sunday" Then
                oSht_Input.Cells(Rows, 16).value = .Index(periodSheet.Range("B:H"), .Match(dateCell, periodSheet.Range("A:A"), 0), 1)
            ElseIf rollupDataFile.GroupByPeriod Like "*Monday" Then                    
                oSht_Input.Cells(Rows, 16).value = .Index(periodSheet.Range("B:H"), .Match(dateCell, periodSheet.Range("A:A"), 0), 2)

.... code continues
```

Edit: Decided to add in a little more context for better clarification based on the initial feedback.

`dateCell` will take in the value of a cell, which is definitely a date value. The  Column A in periodSheet contains EVERY single date from January 1st 2000 to December 31st 2020, essentially covering all possible dates. You can safely assume that the value from the `dateCell` will be within this range of 20 years.

**1.** This is the oSht_Input, where Column G is the date
[image: This is the oSht_Input, where Column G is the date]

**2.** This is the PeriodMetadata sheet, where I am trying to match to Column A (which contains every single date of year 2000-2020 before finding the value based on the .index function.
[image: This is the PeriodMetadata sheet, where I am trying to match to Column A (which contains every single date of year 2000-2020 before finding the value based on the .index function]

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27302794/vba-match-type-mismatch

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett that's because my previous exploration was on Android development, and most of the stuff given didn't really help solve my problem. But I do accept answers once they are of help/solve the problem, and thank everyone else for their inputs either way. If an upvote is what you really want as appreciation then fine, I'll just give it to you (not sure why this discussion is taking place, first time getting nitpicked on such things)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett noted. I'll explore further while waiting for more advice/solutions then, thanks

Comment: Does doing the same `MATCH` as a formula in a cell work?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Yes, doing that works in excel formula, so perhaps its a data formatting issue?

Comment: Using the `Match()` function in VBA, I find that converting to `Long` when working with dates usually does the trick.

Comment: @SO yea I've thought about that. I've checked the custom formatting and it is still a date format. I've also tried setting Column A to Short Date, and did a CDate() function to the dateCell value, still doesn't work

Comment: Try using `CLng()` instead. Excel stores dates as numbers, sometimes you have to bow to this fact in VBA.

Comment: @SO RIGHT! That seems to at least remove the error for now and I'm getting correct matches! Thanks so much for your help, your quick comment has been very useful (although I'm not sure why this is even needed, so unnecessary!) If you can put it as an answer I can help to accept (before I get flamed for being unappreciative again for adding "noise" with just thanks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `CLng()` or `.Value2` instead when working with dates:

```
Sub SO()
'// C3 = "03/02/2015"
'// A1:A14 = "01/02/2015" to "14/02/2015"
'// All cells formatted as dates

'// This will NOT work:
Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("C3").Value, Range("A1:A14"), 0)

'// This WILL work:
Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("C3").Value2, Range("A1:A14"), 0)

'// This WILL also work:
Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Match(CLng(Range("C3").Value), Range("A1:A14"), 0)

End Sub
```

This is because of the way Excel stores dates as numbers - something which sometimes has to be accounted for in VBA

Comment: Yea seems to work for now, I just have to solve some minor logic issues now rather than the 1004 Error. Thank you so much once again!

Comment: Wha??? And amazingly, `Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("C3"), Range("A1:A14"), 0)` works, even though it should be implicitly using the default property, `.Value`. I don't get it. Has to be a bug. Either way, nicely spotted.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett This is where I hit my knowledge boundary - I know that without specifying, VBA will use `.Value` as the default range method, but is there some level of evaluation going on there that produces the `Long` instead of the `Date` data type? - Possibly better suited to a chat than a comment admittedly. I'll try some tests, and maybe try debugging in VS and see what I get - If I find anything I'll update my answer accordingly :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett follow-up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29533627/default-range-method-produces-unexpected-results

Answer (score 3):

When no match is found, that's the error you get.

In the example below, for instance,

```
MsgBox WorksheetFunction.Match(4, Range("A1:A4"), 0)
```

works fine, returning "4" as expected, but

```
MsgBox WorksheetFunction.Match(5, Range("A1:A4"), 0)
```

throws the "Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class" error.

[image]

Also [see this note](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27302794/vba-match-type-mismatch) on how `Worksheetfunction` and `Application` behave differently.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting this, I have added extra information as you've suggested. Will try to work on more screenshots in the meantime to illustrate my problem better