# Default Range property produces unexpected results

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

As a follow-up question to an answer I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29531742/unable-to-get-match-property-of-the-worksheetfunction-class/29533155) I would like to know why the following doesn't error, is this a possible bug in VBA?

Take the following data:

[image: example data set]
If we use the following VBA code, we will receive an error because we need to use the numeric value of the date to match:

```
'//Produces error  
Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("C3").Value, Range("A1:A14"), 0)
```

and so either of these statements **will** work:

```
'// Cast to Long
Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Match(CLng(Range("C3").Value), Range("A1:A14"), 0)
'// Access .Value2 property directly
Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("C3").Value2, Range("A1:A14"), 0)
```

However as pointed out by [Jean-François Corbett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119775/jean-fran%C3%A7ois-corbett), if we don't specify a property it also works:

```
Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("C3"), Range("A1:A14"), 0)
```

So if `.Value` doesn't work, and this is the default property of the `Range` object - why does it work in the above example?

Could this be a bug? Or is there some level of evaluation taking place that counteracts this?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/office/ff835873.aspx - Lookup_value can be a value (number, text, or logical value) or a cell reference to a number, text, or logical value. So in this case `WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("C3"), Range("A1:A14"), 0)` will not use the default method of the `Range` object but the `Range` object itself.

Comment: Even still, in this scenario `Range("C3").Value` and `Range("C3")` would be evaluated and return the same "dd/mm/yyyy" value to be used in the function instead of the numeric value - so it should still error?

Comment: Sure ;-)? You know exactly how `WorksheetFunction.Match` internally works? I don't know because it is not open source.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to find out! If you use `Debug.Print` for `Range("C3").Value` and `Range("C3")` you get the same output because they are evaluated in the same way - so this makes me think that the underlying code for the `Match()` method has some other evaluation going on...

Comment: Hm, `Debug.Print` must use the default method `.Value` because it needs a value which can be cast to string. My suspicion is `WorksheetFunction.Match` will use the `Range` object. I don't know what it is doing then with this internally.

Comment: Which leads me to think 2 things: a) We may never know the answer to this question. b) VBA can itself imply a required method or value instead of using the default when a specific data type is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is a bug. If you run below macro:

```
Debug.Print Range("C3"), Range("C3").Value, Range("C3").Value2
```

1st two will return returns identical results.

> 3/2/2015 3/2/2015 42065

Which confirms the default property as `Value` for `Range Object`.
It is worth noting though that if you explicitly use `Value` all throughout,  it will work as well.

```
Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("C3").Value, Range("A1:A14").Value, 0)
```

So I think that it is another manifestation of the issue once described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386768/why-am-i-having-issues-assigning-a-range-to-an-array-of-variants/21411922#21411922).

If you don't explicitly define `Value` property for both, Excel is smart enough to assume that you're matching `Values`. However, if you explicitly imply one property but leave Excel guessing for the other, it will not work.

Comment: I tried `.Value` with both arguments - it still didn't work. In fact, if I use `.Value` at all in the 2nd argument the code fails - is it expecting a range object instead of an array?

Comment: MSDN implies that an array can be used as the 2nd argument - I can only think that it may not work here because `.Value` will produce a 2 dimensional array, although again I cannot see why that wouldn't work. This is causing more questions *d'oh*

Comment: Win 7 32bit and XL2010 - you?

Comment: @SO I'm on XL2013. Anyways I can't find a ways to check how `Match` processes it's operation. I just based my answer on the link I've posted.

Comment: Yeah I don't think a definitive answer will arrive soon unfortunately, appreciate the effort though cheers :)