# Type mismatch error 13 in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, type-mismatch

so I am writing code for a macro in VBA, and whenever I try to run it, I always get the same error on one line. What is strange about this is that the line works earlier in the program, but it stops working the second time I use it (I did not change any code; I literally copied and pasted it). This is the code:

```
positioninDailyVisitors = Application.Match(originaldata.Worksheets("Top Visitors Chart").Range(columns(index) & counter + 11), originaldata.Worksheets("Daily Visitors").Range("A5:A627"), 0)
```

A bit of background: `positioninDailyVisitors` is an integer variable, `columns(index)` is an array of type `String` that lists values like "A", "B", etc. Also, I already tried to use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` and it still does not work.

Comment: `columns(index) & counter + 11` is not producing the xlA1 style of range address (e.g. A5:A627) that you think it is.

Comment: Where did you copy and paste it from? Are the originaldata workbooks set? Same sheet names? The error is a type mismatch so it looks like it can't 1) get a value from `originaldata.worksheets("Top Visitors").Range(columns(index) & counter + 11)` (Is the "columns" array set publicly where you pasted it... either that or it can't fathom originaldata.Worksheets("Daily Visitors").Range("A5:A627")`

Comment: I don't know what Jeeped means either, looks fine to me, I take it you're looping with `index` and `counter` these values change one by one to give you a single cell range and therefore the value

Comment: As Jeeped wrote, `columns(index) & counter + 11` is not giving an address like `A1`. Well, you wrote that `columns(index)` have string values, so I think you should convert the calculation to string before joining it to column variable. Try `columns(index) & CStr(counter + 11)`, I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: If `columns` is a local variable, it's hiding/shadowing the global-scope `Columns` member, which returns a `Range` object. This is making your code confusing. Consider making an [edit] to include the declarations for all relevant variables. That said you very very very likely don't need that `columns` string array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Application.Match` doesn't find anything, [it returns a `Variant/Error`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27302888/4604845) to the caller - and you're trying to assign that error to an integer-only variable ==> type mismatch. Betting good money this is your problem since the code works occasionally.

Excuse my sub-par hand-drawing skills:[image]

Modify your code thusly:

```
If Not IsError(Application.Match(originaldata.Worksheets("Top Visitors Chart").Range(columns(index) & counter + 11), originaldata.Worksheets("Daily Visitors").Range("A5:A627"), 0)) Then & _
   positioninDailyVisitors = Application.Match(originaldata.Worksheets("Top Visitors Chart").Range(columns(index) & counter + 11), originaldata.Worksheets("Daily Visitors").Range("A5:A627"), 0)
```

Or perhaps more workable/readable:

```
Dim errVar As Variant
errVar = Application.Match(originaldata.Worksheets("Top Visitors Chart").Range(columns(index) & counter + 11), originaldata.Worksheets("Daily Visitors").Range("A5:A627"), 0)
If Not IsError(errVar) Then positioninDailyVisitors = CInt(errVar)
```

Comment: `Excuse my sub-par hand-drawing skills:` just gonna leave this here... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138031/is-there-a-joke-about-freehand-circles-that-im-oblivious-to/138032#138032

Comment: @MacroMan The meme wouldn't be funny if it weren't true, I suppose? ;)

Comment: Thank you guys!! I was able to fix it.