# Getting the "Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class" error

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting the mentioned error when executing the following line of code:

```
Check_Row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ActiveCell, Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Selection, 0, 1), 0)
```

Both my *ActiveCell* and *Selection* seem to be correctly defined - *ActiveCell* contains some text, and the first Column of *Selection* contains a cell with the value match of *ActiveCell*. Also, when I try to run almost the same code (below) in a freshly opened excel sheet, it is working fine?

```
Sub Test()

Range("start").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
test_selection = Selection

Range("A8").Select

Check_Row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ActiveCell,Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(test_selection, 0, 1), 0)

Range("A9").Value = Check_Row

End Sub
```

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what I might be overlooking here? What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Put `Option Explicit` on top. Declare all variables. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/27302888/11683, then https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683.

Comment: Other than that, the code should work. It probably does what you did not expect it to do (e.g. `test_selection = Selection` copies the cells' values into an array instead or remembering reference to the range), but it works. If it does not for you, it is only because `Match` does not find anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you're trying to do using `.Columns(1)` instead of indexing the Range. I've updated your code as well to avoid using `Select` statements. You should update the first `With` with a proper reference to the sheet that this is on instead of using `ActiveSheet`

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()
    Dim test_selection As Range
    Dim Check_Row As Long

    ' Update with your sheet reference
    With ActiveSheet
        set test_selection = .Range("start").CurrentRegion

        Check_Row = WorksheetFunction.Match(.Range("E17").Value2, test_selection.Columns(1), 0)

        .Range("E25").Value = Check_Row
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Why use `Transpose` at all? `Match` is okay with either rows or columns.

Comment: I was incorrectly assuming there was a reason for the `Index` but you're right

Comment: Now you're incorrectly assuming Match can accept a 2D array or range; it cannot.

Comment: @GSerg Had noticed too - You beat me to updating my answer. Works now

Comment: Also the entire `.End()` business, given that we start from top left, can be replaced with `.Range("start").CurrentRegion`. And while coding it this way instead of with the `Index()` is arguably better, the OP's original code should work too.

Comment: @GSerg Didn't know about `CurrentRegion` that's a handy property