# Receiving an Type Mismatch error while running the code

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using this code to get the data from `Sheets("Data")` code goes and search the first header i.e. `Gross Wage` then `Gross Label` and then `Gross DD`. IF these headers are match then code will copy the values (available in `Sheets("Data")` row 7,8 and 9) then paste the values in `Sheets("Final").Range(G11,H11 and I11)` via transpose.

Pasting sequence is that `Sheets("Final")` Columns C and D have years and months that are change according to the D5 date. And `Sheets("Data")` row 6 has years and quarters which values pasted in the `Sheets("Final")`.

Now the problem is that it is giving an type mismatch error. Can someone please look into this issue. Why the error is occuring.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Your help will highly appreciated.

```
Sub input()

Dim x, y, z, i As Long, ii As Long, iii As Long, iv As Long, lRow As Long
    Dim Output, sCohort As String, lCS As Long, lCE As Long, lMnth As Long
    Dim Hdrs, iGp As Integer, iGdb As Integer, iGsb As Integer

    x = Application.Transpose(Sheet1.[e7].Resize(3))
    For i = LBound(x) To UBound(x)
        If Trim(Split(LCase(x(i)), "-")(1)) = "Gross Wage" Then
            iGp = i
        ElseIf Trim(Split(LCase(x(i)), "-")(1)) = "Gross Label" Then
            iGdb = i
        ElseIf Trim(Split(LCase(x(i)), "-")(1)) = "Gross DD" Then
            iGsb = i
        End If
    Next
    
    lRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
    lCS = Application.Match("Row", Sheet1.Rows(6), 0)
    lCE = Application.Match("Run*", Sheet1.Rows(6), 0)
    x = Sheet1.Cells(6, lCS).Resize(lRow - 5, lCE - lCS)
    y = Sheets("Final").[b11].CurrentRegion
    ReDim z(1 To UBound(y, 1), 1 To 3)
    sCohort = Sheet1.Range("B7")
    lMnth = Sheets("Final").[d11]
    
    Select Case lMnth Mod 3
        
        Case Is = 0: ii = 0
        Case Is = 1: ii = 2
        Case Is = 2: ii = 1
    
    End Select
    
    Select Case lMnth
        
        Case Is < 4: iv = 5
        Case Is < 7: iv = 6
        Case Is < 10: iv = 7
        Case Is < 13: iv = 4
    
    End Select
    
    iii = Application.Choose(lMnth, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, 10, 9, 8)
    
    If sCohort = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
    
    For i = iv To UBound(x, 2)
        
        If x(1, i) Like "Q*" Then
            ii = ii + 3
            z(ii, 1) = x(iGp + 1, i)
            z(ii, 2) = x(iGdb + 1, i)
            z(ii, 3) = x(iGsb + 1, i)
            
        ElseIf x(1, i) Like "Y*" Then
            iii = iii + 12
            z(iii, 1) = x(iGp + 1, i)
            z(iii, 2) = x(iGdb + 1, i)
            z(iii, 3) = x(iGsb + 1, i)
            
        End If
    Next
    
    Sheets("Final").[g10].Resize(UBound(z, 1), UBound(z, 2)) = z
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Application.Match gives type mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27302794/application-match-gives-type-mismatch)

Comment: Most likely your `Match` is failing, so it returns an *error value*, not a `Long`.

Comment: Thank you for helping @Warcupine but its difficult for me to figure out the problem.

Comment: Hi, @Rory so there is any way to fix the problem or should i attached a workbook.

Comment: should it be `application.worksheetfunction.match(...`?

Comment: Tried with @JohnnieL but same error is persisting.

Comment: This only means that it is no any "Row" string in the range your code is searching for (`Rows(6)`).

Comment: can you share row 6 data? The type mismatch is likely because `match` is not matching and so returning an error value which clashes with the type of `lCS`

Comment: Yes! this can be the issue. let me attached an sheet with code and data please look into this @FaneDuru

Comment: workbook is attached @ JohnnieL

Comment: No need of any attachment. It is obvious that the string to be matched does not exist in the searched range. I posted a piece of code to show you how to handle the situation... You can use some other `If ... End If` to switch in a different direction, if there is one...

Comment: Are you sure you need to match the string "Row"? It does not exist in the sheet you shared...

Comment: The problem is that same code is working on original file which has same number of rows same date same cell but not working on this. @FaneDuru

Comment: Importantly @Learning row 6 needs to contain "column headings" of "Row" and "Run*" to locate what data to process but you dont have that in this later sheet so you are not providing the input in the way the macro is expecting ...

Comment: This only means that in the "original file" there is a string "Row" on the sixth row... It cannot be identic. Otherwise, VBA will return exactly the same error. In the workbook you shared there is no such string in the whole (Data) sheet. You missed something when tried copying the "original file", I think.

Comment: Here is the Orginal Sheet1 data https://ibb.co/CzNNwF9 @FaneDuru

Comment: Let me check it once again @FaneDuru

Comment: That was not the "Original Sheet1"... It what a picture showing a partial part of it. Nobody can search for a string in a picture.

Comment: Let me update the original file

Comment: If updating means to write "Row" somewhere in the sixth row, but following the logic of "the original file", the problem should be disappearing...

Comment: Exactly But now its the code is pasting  Data sheet row6 values instead of 7,8 and 9 into Sheet Final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the error in this way:

```
If Not IsError(Application.match("Row", Sheet1.Rows(6), 0)) Then
    lCS = Application.match("Row", Sheet1.Rows(6), 0)
Else
    MsgBox "No any ""Row"" string could be found in """ & Sheet1.Rows(6).Address & """ row..."
    Exit Sub 'the sub is exited here
             'you ca use here (instead of exiting) another Match for a different
             'string or range, if this helps somehow...
End If
```

Comment: I have updated the Original File @FaneDuru

Comment: @Learning: It contains "Row" on "E6" cell... Your file contains "NA". So you should search for "NA" Not for "Row", which looks to be only a marker.

Comment: Yes! that was the problem Then where is the "Run" @ FaneDuru now it is givig an error for run

Comment: @Learning: In column "CM" there is something like "RunFilter ID"... But why do  not use the Find search Excel window? `Ctrl + F` and type the string to be searched for... And you may adapt your code with the above suggestion. Just in case you missed such a marker.

Comment: I found it @FaneDuru and now code is working fine but not pasting the result.

Comment: I think the problem has been resolved now the new problem has been occured let me post a new question. Thank you so much for the help

Comment: What does it mean? Did you understand the logic of these markers placing? It should be one behind their position. If the first one is relatively clear, the second one, I do not know what kind of meaning it has. Can't you ask the one designing the code about what was the logic of applying it in a specific position? Not knowing what you need accomplishing, it is impossible to imagine where it must be placed. But if you do not understand the logic behind these placement, your new question will be for nothing...

Comment: Yes i will ask him he is not available right now @FaneDuru. Yes i understand that why he used the match functions