# Using Application.WorksheetFunction.Match returns type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I am trying to get Application.WorksheetFunction.Match to find a value in the next row in a range, in a specific column and match it to a list of values in another worksheet column, setting a = a specific value, if no error is returned.

The code I currently have is:

```
Dim caseSearch As String
Dim caseCell As Range
Dim moveSearch As String
Dim moveCell As Range

caseSearch = "caseset"
moveSearch = "movementset"

Set caseCell = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:=caseSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

Set moveCell = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:=moveSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If caseCell Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "caseset column not found"
ElseIf moveCell Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "movementset column not found"
End If


Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim lRow As Long
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

Set rng = ws.Range("A2:A" & lRow)

For Each row In rng.Rows
    If Not IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(row.Columns(caseCell).Value, tcc.Columns(1), 0)) Then
        a = tcc.Cells("C2")
    Else:
        a = tcc.Cells("C3")
    End If
   
Next row
```

Comment: The second argument in MATCH should be the address (eg. A2:B4). You are passing in a column.

Comment: Ok so I amended to tcc.Range("A2:A") but I still receive the type mismatch error

Comment: I think it is the first parameter.  What is the value of `row.Columns(caseCell).Value`? The Columns() call is expecting an index, you are supplying a Range. Also your For Each is just operating on a single column, so row will just be a single cell anyway.

Comment: The value of 'row.Columns(caseCell).Value' is intended to be the current row in the range, column number matching caseCell's current cell value. If that makes sense. Further up caseCell is set as the column where 'caseset' is found as the header.

Comment: `Set rng = ws.Range("A2:A" & lRow)` ... you only have one column in that range, so it doesn't really matter what caseCells value is. Perhaps you meant `row.Columns(caseCell.Value)` instead? But in any case if caseCell.Value is anything other than 1 you will get an error.

Comment: @KristianMay try just "A:A" as second param.

Comment: Ok so in that case I need to Set rng = column caseCell row 2 to the last populated row then set my first parameter in .Match = current row caseCell's .Value

Comment: See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27302794/application-match-gives-type-mismatch There is a (somewhat bizarre) difference between Application.Match() and Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(). If you want to use IsError() then you need to use Application.Match().

Answer (score 0):

### Match with `Application.Match`

- Here's an example of how you could 'set it up'.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UseApplicationMatch()

    Const caseSearch As String = "caseset"
    Const moveSearch As String = "movementset"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim caseCell As Range
    Set caseCell = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:=caseSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If caseCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "caseset column not found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim caseCol As Long: caseCol = caseCell.Column
    
    Dim moveCell As Range
    Set moveCell = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:=moveSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If moveCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "movementset column not found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim moveCol As Long: moveCol = moveCell.Column
    
    Dim tcc As Worksheet: Set tcc = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim t1 As Long: t1 = tcc.Cells("C2").Value
    Dim t2 As Long: t2 = tcc.Cells("C3").Value
    
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ws.Range("A2:A" & lRow)
    
    Dim fCell As Range
    Dim Result As Long
    For Each fCell In rng.Cells
        If IsNumeric(Application.Match(fCell.EntireRow.Columns(caseCol).Value, _
                tcc.Columns(1), 0)) Then
            Result = t1
        Else
            Result = t2
        End If
    Next fCell
    
End Sub
```